# js how to prototype the form element?

Tags: javascript, forms, prototype

this works:
String.prototype.myfunction = function (){}

But this not really:
Form.prototype.myfunction = function (){}

how to make the protoype work for a form element?
Thank you

Comment: What makes you think there is a `Form` constructor? Form element is instance of `HTMLFormElement` constructor.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can't do what your question asks (it doesn't really make any sense), but if you would describe what you really want to do then someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Form` constructor. `<form>` element is instance of the [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) constructor which implements the `HTMLElement` interface.

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.myfunction = function (){}
```

It should be noted that modifying `prototype` of `HTMLElement` interface is considered a bad practice.

Comment: +1, worth                                                a read: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: why is a bad practice? Is it is okay to modify the String?

Comment: The article that @Bergi has recommended answers your question.